# PE: Relation between SizeOfRawData and VirtualSize fields of the section header

Tags: windows, assembly, windows-10, portable-executable

I see that for sections in image files the `VirtualSize` field is the total size of the section when loaded into memory, while the `SizeOfRawData` field is the size of the section's initialized data on disk.

While examining an `.idata` section, the `VirtualSize` field was set to 0x14, while the `SizeOfRawData` field was set to 0x400.

Why would the linker - in this case MinGW `ld` - make the file section so large, while the section when loaded into memory is only a fraction it's size?

Also, what is the purpose of the `VirtualSize` field? Why not always load the whole section, i.e. load the `SizeOfRawData` bytes?

I don't see a description or their relation in the official PE documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SizeOfRawData(size of raw data sections in the image file) is always multiple [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.FileAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

**FileAlignment**

> The alignment of the raw data of sections in the image file, in bytes.
>   The value should be a power of 2 between 512 and 64K (inclusive). The
>   default is 512. If the SectionAlignment member is less than the system
>   page size, this member must be the same as SectionAlignment.

the purpose of the **VirtualSize** field is how many memory need allocate and copy for section. without this field how loader can know this ?

**VirtualSize** can be more or less than **SizeOfRawData**.

we for example can have only several bytes of initialized actual data in section and no uninitialized data - so **VirtualSize** will be only several bytes size, while **SizeOfRawData** 512 bytes

in another case in `.data` or `.bss` section - can be no initialized data at all (so **SizeOfRawData** == 0) but **VirtualSize** != 0.

so loader is allocate `(VirtualSize + SectionAlignment - 1) & ~(SectionAlignment-1)` bytes for section and copy `min(VirtualSize, SizeOfRawData)` bytes to it from file

Comment: Thank you very much. Doesn't .data always holds initialized data only? Also, where do you get "(VirtualSize + PAGE_SIZE - 1) & ~(PAGE_SIZE-1)" from? If it is possible, could you point me to your source? I'd like to read more on this topic :-)

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen size of section must be aligned to SectionAlignment size (usual this is PAGE_SIZE (by default) - can some look here - MiCreateImageFileMap - http://gate.upm.ro/os/LABs/Windows_OS_Internals_Curriculum_Resource_Kit-ACADEMIC/WindowsResearchKernel-WRK/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/mm/creasect.c - MI_ROUND_TO_SIZE(LENGTH,ALIGNMENT) macro

Comment: What if section contains both uninitialized and initialized data? Then the loader copy too much, because SizeOfRawData is 512?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen yes, you right - .data usual containing both uninitialized and initialized data.
for example we have cbInit(0xc0 bytes) and cbUninit(0x160 bytes), FileAlignment = 0x200
`SizeOfRawData = ROUND_TO_SIZE(cbInit, FileAlignment) = 0x200`
`VirtualSize = cbInit + cbUninit = 0x220`
loader copy `min(SizeOfRawData,VirtualSize)=min(0x200,0x220)=0x200` bytes - so partial overwrite uninitialized data. but this is not problem because linker fill initialized data padding with 0 bytes.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen however you can by self do little test - write program with small init data and big uninit (say char g_test[0x200];) - look in some PEView what generated, than change bytes in the end of .data to non zero and look what be in g_test[0x200] memory after exe start

Comment: "because linker fill initialized data padding with 0 bytes." - are you sure it is not the loader that pad with 0 bytes? Also, why is it wrong that uninitialized data is nonzero? Doesn't uninitialized mean that the data can have any value :-) ?

Comment: yes, of course - i say about data in file - this do linker. how loader can be related at this stage ?! i not say directly that this is error, however with standard linker and windows environment uninitialized data always zero fill. very often in code assume that global uninit vars is 0 initially

Comment: Thanks your help :-)